# Generic sparse matrix addition

Tags: java, generics, sparse-matrix

I have an assignment where Im supposed to finish the implementation on a generic sparse matrix. Im stuck on the addition part. The matrix is only going to support numbers so I had it extend Number hoping I could then add the numbers, thats wrong. The data structure is NOT an array, it is essentially 2 linked lists. (one for rows and one for columns) Here is the code in question:

```
public MatrixSparse<? extends Number> addition(MatrixSparse<? extends Number> A, MatrixSparse<? extends Number> B, MatrixSparse<? extends Number> result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            // set (i, j) to the sum of A(i,j) and B(i,j) is giving me an error
            // "+" is undefined for type capture#2-? etc.
            result.set(i, j, (A.get(i, j) + B.get(i, j)));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the class header + class variables:

```
class MatrixSparse<T extends Number> { 
final Links r[]; 
final Links c[];
final int rows, columns; 
final T zero;
```

any suggestions about how to implement this add method?

Comment: Do you want `MatrixSparse<? extends Number>` or `MatrixSparse<T extends Number>`?

Comment: @Michael it doesnt matter what the header looks like, I just want it to work for floats and int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating then that as a mental/school exercise: You cannot add two generics together with "+" operator - operators are not "genericable" and you cannot overload them in Java (pretty much different than C++) and auto-boxing does not help. The only thing you can do I think is to write a generic T add(T paramLeft,T paramRight) in your Matrix and do something like that:

```
if (paramLeft instanceof Integer) {
     return new Integer(((Integer)paramLeft).intValue()+ ((Integer)paramRight).intValue());
} elseif (paramLeft instanceof Double) { 
     ....
}
```

Comment: I think perhaps some of the confusion is because auto-boxing makes it look like "+" is indeed overloaded.

Comment: Actually, a better idea would be to have an object of type `Operations<T>` or similar which does the addition (and later multiplication, too), and is passed to the matrix objects. You then implement `Operations<Integer>` and `Operations<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have three suggestions:

1. Start writing code.  It looks like you posted the skeleton you were already given to start and expect people here to fill it out for you.  Post some code and ask a specific question when something goes wrong.
2. Can you write a successful non-sparse matrix addition?  At least you'll have that worked out before you start.
3. I'd forget about generics until you have something working.  Add a matrix of integers or doubles first, then add generics.

Comment: sigh... this is my code. I know how to make a regular matrix, non-generic, generic whatever. I have done all of this before. I just want to know how to go about adding matricies when the type is unknown. It WILL be an integer or floating point so there are no worries.

Comment: dont just assume im asking people to "fill in for me" This is some code, and this is a specific question that I asked when something went wrong

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to write your own SparseMatrix? The problem is pretty generic and it is for sure reinventing the wheel if you try to do it yourself. Quick google search shows for example:

http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/

Which is good if LGPL licence is not scaring you away, but I am sure there are plenty of other places you can get ready and tested implementation that will be good for use. I'd rather spend time on finding solution rather than inventing it again.

Comment: its an assignment, I dont necessarily WANT to do this but i have to.

Comment: I am sure you can try to check with whoever makes the decision if you can "stand on the shoulder of giants" and get it working and tested in 5 minutes rather than spend days on it... ... if there is no real reason why to write it again, and you still have to do it .... then change the job. really.

Comment: It's obviously a homework assignment for school and not some random manager at his job (unless I'm sorely mistaken).