# Java Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, types

This code does not compile:

```
public class Calculadora<T> {
    T suma(T a, T b) {
        return (a + b);
    }
}

Calculadora<Integer> c = new Calculadora<Integer>();
System.out.println(c.suma(3, 5));
```

It gives me the error

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

How can I solve it?

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of that question at all. The goal is addition, but the techniques attempted, and the attendant problems with them, are totally different.

Answer (score 4):

T could be any class. It could even be an array. It's not ensured that the "+" operator will work for the given class. 
Why use generics for a calculator anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Compiler does not know the type of `T` so `+` might not be valid on some cases.

But still if you wish you implement this with generics below can be one solution:

```
public class Calculadora<T> {

    Double suma(T a, T b) {
        if (a instanceof Number && b instanceof Number) {
            return (Double.parseDouble(a.toString()) +  Double.parseDouble(b.toString()));
        }
        return 0d;
    }

}
```

**You must override `toString` method of `T` to return number.**

Comment: It will result this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203197/java-generic-addition

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the method you're trying to implement is impossible. Well, at least *for me*. I don't know how to solve it. But anyways, I'll try to explain why you're getting the error:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

This simply means, *What does a `+` do with a type `T`?*

Well, it makes sense when we try to do something like:

```
Calculadora<Integer> c = new Calculadora<Integer>();
```

Because `Integer` can be cast to `int` and the compiler knows exactly how to add `int` with `int` right?

But since `T` can be of any type, what if we do something like:

```
Calculadora<Cat> c = new Calculadora<Cat>();
```

Clearly, we don't know how the hell you will add a `Cat` with another `Cat`. That's why the compiler is giving you that error, it's telling you, *I don't know how to add this Type together. I can only add numbers and Strings.*

Hope this'll help. :)

**EDIT 2:**

Well, the way I see it, if you really need to do something like that, you're going to have to change your class and method declaration a bit, something like:

```
//Limit only the Generics to subtypes of Number
class Calculadora<T extends Number> {

    //Return a specific type (Can be Double, Float, Long, etc.)
    Integer suma(T a, T b) {        
        //Change this based on your return type (Can be double, float, long, etc.)
        int sum = 0;
        if (a instanceof Number && b instanceof Number) {
            //Change this accordingly too (Can be doubleValue(), floatValue(), longValue(), etc.)
            sum = a.intValue() + b.intValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This is only for `Integer`. You can change this to any subtype of `Number` if you want.